# Elements won't show, appear to be hidden behind background image?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Can soneone give me a hint as to why my element(id="stuff") won't show?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
 <title>blah</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection">

body{     
    width: 100%;     
    height: 100%;     
    margin: 0;     
    padding: 0;      
}
img#background {     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 0;     
    left: 0;     
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100%; 
    margin:0;     
    padding:0;
} 
#stuff{
background: black;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
z-index: 2;
}


</style> 
</head>
<body>
<img id="background" src="greenbackground.png" alt="Background Image" />
<div id="stuff"><p>stuff</p></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img#background {
   z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b9uUE/3/

Comment: I think a downwote for an accepted answer working on all major browsers should deserve an explanation, so that I could also understand why it's wrong and avoid it in the furute... is it bad practice? or does it cause more problems/incompatibilities?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the body is on a z-index of 0 and if it has a background image then the -1 would hide it behind the body.

Comment: Also, for my case, I needed to set `position: relative;` as with other answers

Answer (score 6):

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).      Adding the position line to #stuff will fix this.

```
#stuff{
 position:relative;
background: black;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Give it a position other than static:

```
#stuff{
    background: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To affect the `z-index` property, you need to use something like `absolute` on the position of the element. Try adding

```
position: absolute;
```

To `#stuff`

Answer (score -1):

Your background image is absolutely positioned. This means it falls outside the normal flow of the document. Basically you're overriding its position and saying position it **here**.

Set img#background `position:relative` and remove the top and left positions.